# Ability to query who is following a specified tag in Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, data-explorer

It would be great if we can query who all are following a particular tag. So something like this should be the query.

```
Select * from Users u
inner join TagUserMap tum on u.Id = tum.UserId
where tum.TagId = @tagId
```

Comment: Why do you need this information?

Comment: Just to know from whom can I expect answer on my question tagged with a particular tag which is not very much popular.

Comment: You can't expect anyone to answer; answering questions is completely optional, regardless of one's knowledge of a particular subject area. Just because a user follows a tag doesn't mean that they want people who ask questions in those tags to try to contact them and get them to answer their questions.

Comment: There is no `@downvoter!`. There is just me, the only person to reply to your question, and so the system assumes that you're talking to me (rather than talking to yourself) and notifies me that you've left me a comment. That's annoying, so please don't do it. It's also annoying for another reason: downvotes are completely anonymous, and that is completely by design. No one is required to tell you why they've downvoted. If they didn't leave a comment, that's their choice. I certainly can't tell you, but [reading the FAQ might](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your underlying aim:

> Just to know from whom can I expect answer on my question tagged with a particular tag which is not very much popular.

is already served; for example, using [elmah](/questions/tagged/elmah) as an example: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/elmah/topusers

However, ***do not*** use this to create a list of people to harass to answer your question. That will lead to.... consequences ;p

Comment: I don't think one can directly contact to a particular user unless the user has given its contact in his profile description. Or is there any way?

Comment: Thanks very much! I was looking at wrong place for that info :)

Comment: @Ismail why would you be needing to contact the users?

Comment: OK. I will rewrite it with the missing bit which I wrongly assumed to be implicit. I don't think one can directly contact to a particular user to `harass him` using SO unless the user has given its contact in his profile description. Or is there any way?

Comment: @Ismail occasionally we've seen users go around likely users leaving "please look at this [link]" comments on dozens of posts. That behaviour is very unwelcome.

Comment: Oh I see! Suppose I asked a question explaining my scenario and I got a prompt answer from one person and it got accepted immediately. Now after that I ask another question with the same scenario linking the first question for the context and I know that the person who answered my first question will also be able to (in fact quickly) answer this question with less reading. So is it not acceptable even in this case to post a link in comment and request a help to the answerer of the first question?

Comment: @Ismail in the follow up scenario, yes it would be fine to leave a comment on the answer to the original post saying "I posted a follow up to this [here]"

Comment: Al-right @Marc! Thanks very much :-) You guys simply rock. You guys develop great software and also interact so much on SO and meta. I wonder where do you get so much of time from.

Comment: @Ismail er, this is our full time job, so... from there.